# How can to access the CTR values in Catboost?

Tags: catboost, catboostregressor

When using Catboost on data with a categorical variable, CTR values are calculated during training for each value of this categorical feature.  These values are then used to determine paths through the tree at prediction time.  Given a trained model, how can I access these CTR values?

(Please note that our model uses non symmetric trees, for which model export to Python or C++ is not supported.)

What I've tried / partial progress: I can see the CTR values in the JSON export, but these are stored next to the hash of each feature value, not the feature value itself.  If I knew how the hash was calculated (and what exactly was hashed, i.e. is it just the feature name?) then I would have the CTR values.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this took some effort, so I'll answer here for others.

The CTR values are available in the JSON export of a Catboost model.  Specifically, you
can find the CTR values in `jsonexport['ctr_data'][feature_identifier]['hash_map']`. This is a list that looks like:

```
hash_value, ctr_0, ctr_1, ..., ctr_k, hash_value, ctr_0, ctr_1, ..., ctr_k, hash_value, ...
```

The hash values are hashes of the categorical feature values, while the integers `ctr_i` are raw counts, which are combined to form the true CTR values in the manner described [here](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic).  The hash values are computed in the following manner:

```
from cityhash import CityHash64

MAX_INT = 0xffffffffffffffff
MAGIC_MULT = 0x4906ba494954cb65

def feature_value_hash(fv):
    """
    For the provided feature value (a string) return its corresponding key to the hash table of CTR values (a string).
    """
    ch = CityHash64(fv.encode('ascii'))
    ch_32_lsb = (np.uint64(ch) & np.uint64(0xffffffff)).astype(np.int32)
    return str((MAGIC_MULT * ((MAGIC_MULT * int(ch_32_lsb)) & MAX_INT)) & MAX_INT)
```

Note that it is crucial to use [this specific](https://github.com/Amper/cityhash/tree/4f02fe0ba78d4a6d1735950a9c25809b11786a56) older version of Cityhash.  The hash function above was deduced from the Python export and was correct for our model (which used counters of type "Buckets").

Comment: Are there any solutions that work with modern Python?